# In Http Methods, what is purpose of having differet method names

Tags: http

In Http Methods, what is purpose of having differet method name like(putmapping/postmapping/deletemapping/getmapping), when i can handle from backend logic

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the **semantics of the request**.

See the following quote from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the document that currently defines the semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

> The request method token is the primary source of request semantics;
> it indicates the purpose for which the client has made this request
> and what is expected by the client as a successful result. [...]

Here's a brief description of some HTTP methods defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) (click the links to check the full method definition):

- [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1): Transfer a current representation of the target resource.
- [`HEAD`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2): Same as [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), but only transfer the status line and header section.
- [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3): Perform resource-specific processing on the request payload.
- [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4): Replace all current representations of the target resource with the request payload.
- [`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5): Remove all current representations of the target resource.